# Binary Search Tree in C# Search Method

Tags: c#, data-structures, binary-search-tree

```
public bool Searchtree(Node root, int target)
    {
        if (root == null) return false;

        else if (target < root.data)
            Searchtree(root.left, target);

        else if (target > root.data)
            Searchtree(root.right, target);

        if (target == root.data)
        {
            //Console.WriteLine("Found: "+root.data);
            return true;
        }

        else
            return false;
    }
```

This is a method to search an integer in a Binary Search Tree

Method call would be: `binary.Searchtree(binary.root, 2);`

But it Always returns False, even though it prints the Writeline.

Comment: You need to return the results of the recursive calls to `Searchtree`.

Comment: Put it another way: in your current code above, what is the purpose of those recursive calls to `Searchtree`?

Comment: Think i got it, now the recursive calls just do nothing.          
`return Searchtree(root.right, target);` would do the trick i think?

Comment: Thanks Oli Charlesworth and LeffeBrune

Answer (score 4, accepted):

return the result of calls to Searchtree:

```
public bool Searchtree(Node root, int target)
{
    if (root == null)
        return false;
    else if (target < root.data)
        return Searchtree(root.left, target);
    else if (target > root.data)
        return Searchtree(root.right, target);

    return true;
}
```